# How to make a transaction in cosmos DB with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, azure-cosmosdb

** Edited - Solution below **

I am trying to insert data to Azure cosmos DB if its not exist but can't find a way to do it in one transaction.

the current way I'm doing it is by first getting it from cosmos and if it's throwing Not found exception then insert, otherwise update it.
the issue with that is that between the get and insert someone can push an object so this approach is unsafe.

code snippet:

```
static async fetchOrgConfigurationTableByQuery(orgId: string): Promise<OrgConfigurationTable> {
    const { container } = await getContainer(Constants.CosmosRegional, Constants.OrgConfigurationTableName);
    const orgConfigurations = await container.items.query(`SELECT * from c WHERE c.OrgId = "${orgId}"`).fetchAll();
    const orgConfiguration = orgConfigurations.resources.find(() => true) as OrgConfigurationTable;
    if (!orgConfiguration) {
        return;
    }

    const orgConfigurationWithDefaults = new OrgConfigurationTable();
    for (const [key] of Object.entries(orgConfiguration)) {
        orgConfigurationWithDefaults[key] = orgConfiguration[key];
    }

    return orgConfigurationWithDefaults;
}

static async upsertOrgConfiguration(
    orgConfiguration: OrgConfigurationTable,
    failOnEtagMismatch = false
): Promise<OrgConfigurationTable> {
    const requestOptions = getRequestOptions(orgConfiguration, failOnEtagMismatch);
    const { container } = await getContainer(Constants.CosmosRegional, Constants.OrgConfigurationTableName);
    const returnValue = await container.items.upsert<OrgConfigurationTable>(orgConfiguration, requestOptions);

    return returnValue?.resource;
}
```

what I have:

```
let orgConfig: Cosmos.OrgConfigurationTable = null;
try {
    orgConfig = await fetchOrgConfigurationTableByQuery(orgId);
} catch (error) {
      if (!error instanceof Cosmos.OrgNotFoundException) {
        log(error)
      }
}

orgConfig = {
    ...orgConfig,
    attribute: value,
    ...(!orgConfig && { Key: { Value: orgId } }),
};
await upsertOrgConfiguration(orgConfig)
```

what I want - to dont get before upsert:

```
let orgConfig = {
    attribute: value,
    Key: { Value: orgId },
};
await upsertOrgConfiguration(orgConfig) // if exist update, else insert - in single transuction.
```

or some way to do somthing like this:

```
transaction {
    let orgConfig: Cosmos.OrgConfigurationTable = null;
    try {
        orgConfig = await fetchOrgConfigurationTableByQuery(orgId);
    } catch (error) {
          if (!error instanceof Cosmos.OrgNotFoundException) {
            log(error)
          }
    }
    await upsertOrgConfiguration(orgConfig)
}
commit
```

any ideas?

** Solution: **

I used etag to solve this issue: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/database-transactions-optimistic-concurrency

Here is the code I used:

```
static async atomicUpdateToContainer<T extends Document>(container: Container, docId: string, updateFunc: (document: T) => Promise<T & Resource>): Promise<T> {
    try {
        // Run the update function with retry in case of conflict due to etag mismatch
        const result = await TaskExecutor.runWithRetry(async () => {
            const queryResult = await container.item(docId).read<T>();
            let itemToUpdate = queryResult?.resource;

            if (!itemToUpdate) {
                const message = `Document with id: ${docId} not found in container: ${container.id}`;
                throw new DocumentNotFoundException(message);
            }

            const requestOptions = Cosmos.getRequestOptions(itemToUpdate, true /* failOnEtagMismatch */);
            itemToUpdate = await updateFunc(itemToUpdate);
            return await container.item(docId).replace<T>(itemToUpdate, requestOptions);
        }, DEFAULT_RETRY_COUNT);

        return result?.resource;
    } catch (error) {
        // log the error and re-throw
        throw error;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you’ve written. Also include the details about the SDK you’re using.

Comment: added more details, thanks.